# Fail to use quanteda::dictionary() to locate dictionaries

Tags: r, lda, quanteda

I have finally almost read the entire quanteda tutorial in two weeks time, and now I have arrived the Seeded LDA part: https://tutorials.quanteda.io/machine-learning/topicmodel/

This code from the tutorial got an error,

**Code:**

dict_topic <- dictionary(file = "../dictionary/topics.yml")
print(dict_topic)

**error:**

Error in dictionary.default(file = "../dictionary/topics.yml") :
File does not exist: ../dictionary/topics.yml

How can I fix it, get the dictionaries function and continue my journey? Do I need to reinstall, or miss installed something? Actually I skipped all parts in the tutorial wherever dictionary is needed, I just really need some help.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Best regards,

Kar

Please help, I cannot find dictionary file specified in the code at all in the local folder of quanteda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the file in the [Git repository](https://github.com/quanteda/tutorials.quanteda.io/tree/master/content/dictionary).